# Problema de formato en html de Django

Tags: html, css, django

Luego de mucho luchar finalmente la encuesta muestra las opciones correctas en el lugar correcto, pero no logro darle un formato... bonito, es decir q se desplieguen en una linea con espacios equitativos entre cada opcion.
No solo no se centran, sino que siempre la primera opcion de la primera encuesta está excesivamente separada de todas las demas.

[image: Mi pagina]

Este es el codigo html:

```
<article style="color: cornsilk; background-color:  rgb(153, 152, 160); width: 70%; margin:0 auto; border-radius: 1%;">
{% if encuesta %}<!--Si hay algo en encuesta entonces-->
    <ul>
        <form  style="display: inline;padding: 40px; color: cornsilk;" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    {% for question in encuesta %}
        <p style="text-align:center;">{{question.pregunta}}</p>
        
        {% for choice in opcion %}
        <span style="text-align:center; margin: 0 auto;">
            {% if question.id == choice.id_pregunta_id %}
            <tr>{{choice.opciones}}</tr>
            <input type="checkbox" name="opciones"></span>
            
            {% endif %}
        </form>
        {% endfor%}
        
    
        <p></p>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar información" style="margin-left: 370px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <p></p>
    </ul>
{% else %}<!--Si no hay nada en encuesta-->
    <p>Sin encuestas disponibles</p>
{% endif %}
</article>
```

Necesito ayuda para que quede centrado y con una separacion razonable entre cada opcion.
Aqui están las vistas:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Encuesta, Choice

# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render
#from AppServicios.models import Servicio 
# Create your views here.

def encuesta(request):
    encuesta=Encuesta.objects.all()
    Opcion=Choice.objects.all()#filter(pk=id)
    return render(request, "AppPoll/Poll.html", {"encuesta":encuesta, "opcion": Opcion})
```

Comment: Utiliza css y si propiedad `text-aling`

Comment: Estas usando un modelform o un form? si puedes comparte el codigo de tu views.py y tu forms.py

Comment: Aqui no estoy usando forms.py, pero si compartiré las vistas.

Comment: ¿Por qué la etiqueta `django`?, no creo que tenga algo que ver, a lo mucho dependerá del *html* y el problema se podría solucionar con *css*, no tiene nada que ver las views que renderizas

Comment: Porque el html tiene ciclos for e if q son propios de Django.